# multidimensional array with keys

Tags: ios, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looping through several classes in my database, and I would like to save their data into a multidimensional array. I'm doing this by using the `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
[homesDic addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[object objectForKey:@"title"], image, [cityObject objectForKey:@"navn"], [userName objectForKey:@"name"],profileImage, nil]];
```

The problem is that I'm going to put a lot of information in this array and I therefore think it would be much easier to access the data if it was associated with a key.

I've looked a little into `NSMutableDictionary`, but can't seem to figure out how I can associate a key with each object in the array.

Comment: Create a model object with properties for each "column" in your table(s).

Comment: could u make a small snippet?

Comment: Not easily, no, as it really depends on your problem domain model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *flagDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[flagDict setObject:[object objectForKey:@"title"] forKey:@"title"];
[flagDict setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
[flagDict setObject:[cityObject objectForKey:@"navn"] forKey:@"navn"];
[flagDict setObject:[userName objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
[flagDict setObject:profileImage forKey:@"profileImage"];
//.............
//So on
[homesDic addObject:flagDict];
```